# Get the value of a dynamic element when press button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I am dynamically outputting blocks of data that contain several pieces of information, included is a button that I when pressed will give me the name in that  specific block.

My ejs file

```
<% data.forEach(el => { %>
    <div class="card">
        <img src= "<%= el.image %>" class="card-img-top" alt="">
        <h5 class="card-title"><%= el.name %></h5>
        <p class="card-text">Age: <%= el.age %></p>
        <p class="card-text"><%= el.club %></p>
        <button class="remove-player">Remove Player</button>
    </div>
<% }) %>
```

When I press the button I want to get the value of the name of the element associated with that button, since I have more that one using jQuery will give me multiple values i.e.

```
$('.remove-player').on('click', function() {
    console.log($('.card-title').text());
});
```

I would like to get only the value of the card-title associated with the button being pressed.

Comment: ...but instead, what happens exactly? What's your error?

Comment: try using jQuery `closest()` method to get the closest `h5` element. More info here https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 1):

Use navigation relative to `$(this)`.

```
console.log($(this).siblings(".card-title").text());
```